# Google API REST Get the FilesInFolder Name

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I want to upload a file to a Google drive folder, if the file name is same i want to skip. With the code below i able upload file to Google Drive. But how to get the filename inside a folder?

```
File newFile = GoogleDriveHelper.uploadFile(service, dir, directoryId);
```

I'm referring to google REST [document](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/children/list) when I pass in all the param, it will return the Id in Google Drive.

Thx for Advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get)  pass the fileId to this function. The fileId can be get at [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/children/list)

```
public static void printFile(DriveService service,String fileId)
        {
            try
            {
                File file = service.Files.Get(fileId).Execute();
                Console.WriteLine("Title: " + file.Title);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
            }
        }
```